# Hbase shell command with the given time range as row key

Tags: hbase

I have the following data structure in hbase table,

```
fb60b40ce747_1552305177484   column=detail:ble_mac, timestamp=1552305177487, value=FB60B40CE747
fb60b40ce747_1552305177484   column=timeline:date_created, timestamp=1552305177487, value=1552305177484                                                              
fb60b40ce747_1552305177484   column=timeline:last_updated, timestamp=1552305177487, value=1552305177484
fb60b40ce747_1552305183307   column=detail:ble_mac, timestamp=1552305183310, value=FB60B40CE747
fb60b40ce747_1552305183307   column=timeline:date_created, timestamp=1552305183310, value=1552305183307                                                              
fb60b40ce747_1552305183307   column=timeline:last_updated, timestamp=1552305183310, value=1552305183307 
fb60b40ce747_1552305194792   column=detail:ble_mac, timestamp=1552305194795, value=FB60B40CE747
fb60b40ce747_1552305194792   column=timeline:date_created, timestamp=1552305194795, value=1552305194792                                                              
fb60b40ce747_1552305194792   column=timeline:last_updated, timestamp=1552305194795, value=1552305194792
```

I am trying to extract the details by specifying the time range (ie.., MAC Address_TimeStamp which is a key row here). I have used the following hbase shell command,

```
scan 'mindlogic:ble_log',{STARTROW => 'fb60b40ce747_1552305120484', ENDROW => 'fb60b40ce747_1552305204792',LIMIT=>1}
```

The problem with this command is, I am unable to extract the most recent record. Here the most recent record is, "fb60b40ce747_1552305194792"

I have tried with another command, which is

```
scan 'mindlogic:ble_log',{LIMIT => 1,FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('detail','ble_mac',=, 'binary:FB60B40CE747') AND SingleColumnValueFilter('timeline','last_updated',>=, 'binary:1552305120484') AND SingleColumnValueFilter('timeline','last_updated',<=, 'binary:1552305204792')"}
```

Now my question is, How to get the result like below one,

```
Expected Output :-
fb60b40ce747_1552305194792   column=detail:ble_mac, timestamp=1552305194795, value=FB60B40CE747
fb60b40ce747_1552305194792   column=timeline:date_created, timestamp=1552305194795, value=1552305194792                                                              
fb60b40ce747_1552305194792   column=timeline:last_updated, timestamp=1552305194795, value=1552305194792
```